# TypeError: Cannot set property 'ar' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

i set variable ar at the first. 
like

```
export class HomePage {
ar:any;
 ... 
 ...
constructor( ...){
 ar=new Array();
...
this.loadEvent();
}
```

and then, on triggered function of constructor,

[image]

I tweaked above function to below

[image]

Why can't I put values from firebase to variable ar?

Comment: Hey it's generally a better idea to post your actual code rather than screenshots of it. It makes it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Also since it looks like you're using VSCode, you might want to install this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode extension that'll format your code for you. Right now it's a little hard to read

Comment: A good read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/2864740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because `this` inside your function passed to `.then` is different from `this` outside your function. Read https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/ for a good explanation on why.

To fix this instead of

```
function (snapshot) {}
```

you need to do

```
(snapshot) => {}
```

which maintains the value of `this` from the outer scope.